# Emacs 24.3.1 ECB 2.40 (built in) CEDET 2.0 (builtin) SEMANTIC 2.2 (builtin) Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size

Tags: emacs, emacs-ecb

When I type `ecb-activite` it results in the following error:

```
ecb-clean-up-after-activation-failure: ECB 2.40: Errors during the layout setup of ECB.
   (error-type: error, 
    error-data: ("Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size"))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

please, install ECB from [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net) and try again?

Comment: I installed  ECB Version: 20131116.1319 from MELPA and still get the same error.  Do I need to disable the built-in one somehow?

Comment: how did you get built-in ECB? Emacs itself doesn't have it, if it came from Linux - then you need to uninistall it...

Comment: I uninstalled all other packages, started with `emacs -Q` then evaled `(add-to-list 'package-archives  '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)`.  After which I installed ecb.  I am still getting the same error.  I created a Backtrace and posted it: https://gist.github.com/m0smith/8261464

Comment: I found a way to work around the issue by using `(ignore-errors (ecb-activate))`.  ECB seems to work as expected if the error is ignored. @alex-ott

Comment: How is `(ignore-errors (ecb-activate))` helping? I get the same result as @flatline.

Answer (score 0):

I installed ECB from both Melpa and from [here](https://github.com/alexott/ecb/), without any luck.  Both give this same error.  Using the (ignore-errors ...) trick to launch it just results in a message "The ECB is now deactivated", and pretty much kills emacs after this point.  Anyone have a way of getting ECB to work with Emacs 24.3?  i'm running from within cygwin, but otherwise am not having a problem with my emacs environment.